# button execution absolutely ignores for-loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton

On button click, the for-loop is absolutely ignored. It just skips over 
the loop and continues executing. Why does this occur. 
The terminal prints "breakpoint" and then "finish" immediately.

Skeleton Code:

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if(SomeClass.someMethod() == true){
           boolean passed = false;
           for(int p = 0; passed = false; p++){
                  //my code...

           }
        System.out.println("breakpoint");
    }
    else{
           someJTextArea.append(...some message...);    
    } 
   System.out.println("finish");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an equals sign, it should be

```
 boolean passed = false;
 for(int p = 0; passed == false; p++){
              //my code...
 }
```

As it is right now, you're not checking the value of `passed` on every iteration but instead you're doing an assignment.

Also, be sure to change the value of `passed` inside the loop to avoid infinite iterations.

Comment: Note that it's neater not to compare booleans like that but instead check for `!passed`.

Comment: thanks...was thinking the solution would be swing Worker or something its amazing how you miss the little things.

Answer (score 1):

```
passed = false
```

means it assigns value `false` to `passed` and then gets evaluated to `false`

change it to

```
passed == false
```

if you want infinite iterations

Answer (score 0):

You declare `boolean passed = false;` and use that as a condition in for loop. `for(int p = 0; passed = false; p++)`

when you say `passed = false` it returns false. So change = to ==

Comment: Logically its wrong. But syntactically its correct. you could write for(int p = 0; passed = false; p++) and compiler wont complain. Compiler take that passed = false as a false.

Answer (score 0):

That's assignment:
    `A = B` 
That's comparing:
    `A == B`

So you need to change your loop to

```
for(int p = 0; passed == false; p++){
```